# How to filter a Collection in Kamva mgm in Go

Tags: mongodb, go

I use the mgm Package (https://github.com/Kamva/mgm) for my mongodb connection from Go. My Models are:

```
type User struct {
mgm.DefaultModel `bson:",inline"`
Name      string             `json:"name"`
}
```

And

```
type App struct {
    mgm.DefaultModel `bson:",inline"`
    UserId      primitive.ObjectID             `json:"userId" bson:"userId"`
    Name    string           `json:"appname,omitempty"`
}
```

I want to get all Apps that have the UserId xy. I get all Apps with

```
apps := []Models.App{}
collection := mgm.Coll(&Models.App{})
err = collection.SimpleFind(&apps, bson.M{})
```

But if i try to use a filter in the bson.M, it returns null. How can i get all with a userID?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that i must convert the objectId, before i can use it.

```
context:=mgm.Ctx()
objID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("6094c6cc92de29f2f6185965")
cursor, err:=mgm.Coll(&Models.App{}).Find(context,bson.D{{"userid",objID }})
```

With this it worked.